# Delete Office365 mails through the API based on Message-ID's

Tags: office365, office365api

I have a bunch of exported emails that now should be deleted inside Office 365.
The Office 365 API provides a `DELETE /me/messages/{messageId}` REST endpoint but the `{messageId}` mentioned there is not the same as the `Message-ID` that can be found inside the exported emails.

The format expected is for example `MAAAkL8DFzPTaS5m....S15YyUlnWAAAcDWOTAAA=` while the Message-ID's are in the `<XYZfooBar123@BAR.test.outlook.com>` format.
Is there any link between these two, any way to get the required ID from an .msg/.eml file or an other way to delete these emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > XYZfooBar123@BAR.test.outlook.com

That is the Internet Message-ID assigned generally by the first Message Transfer Agent in the chain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-ID .You could use this property in a Search for the Message in a Mailbox or as a correlation with Message Tracking Logs. However the Id is not guaranteed unique eg if somebody has sent a Message and copied themselves they would then have a copy of the Message in the SentItems Folder and Inbox folder etc with the same Id.

The MessageId that is required in REST is really the ItemId which is the Identifier that Exchange has assigned to the Item when the item was first saved to the store. This Id is globally unique but changes when items are moved between folders etc eg see. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605828(v=exchg.150).aspx this is for EWS but still holds true for REST however the Id's are a different format  )

When you exported the Messages the ItemId would have be returned in the GET on /Messages.

Depending on how you exported the Messages ? you may have another correlation-id that could be used eg the original EntryId could be converted, PR_SearchKey maybe be used etc.

Comment: Hi Glen, thanks for your answer! The messages were exported using eDiscovery (as PST's) so we did not get the MessageId's that way.
How could I search using the API and the Message-ID? I tried using the `/me/messages?$search=` endpoint but with no result. (I am using the Graph API)

Comment: Use a filter eg https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=internetMessageId eq '<0.1.59.3DD.1D332AC10611282.0@omp.edm.realestate.com.au>' works for me

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!